# Backup Formatted Data

Tags: format, backup, restore, hard-drive

I Formatted My D: dard drive partition and I installed Windows on it by mistake. I would have to Install window to C: drive and that was my mistake.
Is there anyway to get my old data of that was stored in D: drive before format.

Please Help me to do this..

Answer (score 0):

Not without having a second hard disk, or a second computer to mount it to.

Also you would need to have data recovery software to do a complete recovery on something like this.

Basic instructions.
shutdown the computer, secure the drive.
Install another hard disk, format, install windows.
Lately I've been recommending getdataback by runtime.org, it's about $99. You most likely need the ntfs version. Install that, (You can test it without purchasing it but you cannot complete the recovery without installing a license)
shutdown the computer.
slave the old hard disk
change the bios settings, if the drive is not identified.
boot into windows run, get data back for ntfs.
choose formatted media
let it run for a few hours.
select the data you want back, save the recovery, install the license, complete the recovery.

it's as easy as that.

More importantly, stop using the computer as any download or use could destroy the data still sitting on the drive by overwriting the data.